# 16 byte memory alignment using SSE instructions

Tags: intel, sse, memory-alignment

i am trying to get rid of unaligned loads and stores for SSE instructions for my application by replacing the

```
_mm_loadu_ps()
```

by

```
_mm_load_ps()
```

and allocating memory with:

```
float *ptr = (float *) _mm_malloc(h*w*sizeof(float),16)
```

instead of:

```
float *ptr = (float *) malloc(h*w*sizeof(float))
```

However wehen i print the pointer addresses using:

```
printf("%p\n", &ptr)
```

I get output:

```
0x2521d20
0x2521d28
0x2521d30
0x2521d38
0x2521d40
0x2521d48
...
```

This is not 16-byte aligned, even though i used the _mm_malloc function?
And when using the aligned load/store operations for the SSE instructions i yield a segmentation error since the data isn't 16-byte aligned.

Any ideas why it isn't aligned properly or any other ideas to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

---

### Update

Using the

```
printf("%p\n",ptr)
```

solved the problem with the memory alignment, the data is indeed properly aligned.

However i still get a segmentation fault when trying to do an aligned load/store on this data and i'm suspecting it's a pointer issue.

When allocating the memory:

```
contents* instance;
instance.values = (float *) _mm_malloc(h*w*sizeof(float),16);
```

I have a struct with:

```
typedef struct{
  ...
  float** values;
  ...
}contents;
```

In the code i then execute in another function, with a pointer to contents passed as argument:

```
__m128 tmp = _mm_load_ps(&contents.values);
```

Do you guys see anything i am missing?
Thanks for all the help so far :)

Comment: Are you sure, that `h * w * sizeof( float )` is a multiple of 16?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is but h and w are variable. Is it required this is a multiple of 16?

Comment: Yes, of course. This loads 4 floats. So you have to have at least 4 floats available.

Comment: I already handled this with a switch statement when loading the variables, but this isn't required for the memory allocation and isn't the problem, i think it's a problem with pointers but i'm not sure

Comment: Then you have to post the crashing code.

Comment: It looks like you need to change `_mm_load_ps(&contents.values)` to `_mm_load_ps(contents.values)`, since `contents.values` is already a pointer - same problem as your earlier printf issue - you have a tendency to over-dereference. ;-)

Comment: Tried it but i get `error: argument of type "float" is incompatible with parameter of type "const float *"`

Comment: That's not consistent with the code as posted above - I see now you have values as `float **` - is that correct ? Yet you assign the result of `_mm_malloc` to this ???

Comment: yes that is correct. I found out while debugging that it isn't the _mm_load_ps() that is causing the seg fault, but the _mm_store_ps() that's behind it, which stores at the same address `&contents.values` and it gives `Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

Comment: The problem seems to boil down to, you don't know what a pointer vs. a pointer onto a pointer is. struct contents with its values member seems to be really wrong. And if you get a read error on a store instruction, there must be something wrong with the address you pass in.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
printf("%p\n", &ptr)
```

to:

```
printf("%p\n", ptr)
```

It's the memory that ptr is pointing to that needs to be 16 byte aligned, not the actual pointer variable itself.

Comment: Thanks this solved one part of the problem, so the data is properly 16-byte aligned in memory. But i still get a segmentation fault when trying to do an aligned load/store on this data. Are there any common causes of this?

Comment: When you get a seg fault you should drop into your debugger and see what instruction caused it and what the address was - this should tell you all you need to know to fix the problem, e.g. unaligned address, invalid address (out of bounds or null), etc.